# path equation of sin wave profile

Tags: circles

I made a CNC machine to make a sine wave profile around a cylinder but i want to make an equation/s so the user to input some variables like cylinder diameter,frequency ,amplitude and cutter diameter .and the equation/s tell him the Z and C values.
I tested this by using CAM software but this is complex for normal users.[Some videos to explain](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7PTdc6A1RLBNWhiQUxmNEhJZEE?usp=sharing)

Comment: What are $Z$ and $C$?

Comment: Z axis and C axis is a rotational axis about Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the following path in the case where your cylinder axis is aligned with Z-axis : $$f:[0;2\pi]\to\mathbb{R}, f(t) = (r\cos(t), r\sin(t), h+A\sin(kt)-A)$$
where $r$ is the radius of your cylinder, $h$ the height of the cylinder, $A$ half the depth of the wave, and $k$ the number of waves

Comment: thanks , i will try this and tell you

Comment: It works very well thank you